# Is there way to change convolution method in Pytorch? (Or in other Frameworks?)

Tags: c++, arm, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

We are currently developing an optimized convolution algorithm for ARM, in C++. We are using Ubuntu 18.04 for aarch64 on an ARM development board, Odroid N2+ to be exact.

To test the algorithm against other popular methods, (im2col+gemm, FFT, Winograd...) we download Pytorch, and compiled its C++ API, libtorch, natively in our development environment.
But unfortunately it seems there aren't a way to change the convolution algorithm from the given API.

Is there a way to change the convolution algorithm in Pytorch? (Or libtorch?) If not, are there any other frameworks or APIs that would provide optimized implementations of different convolution algorithms for our environment? (ARMv8, aarch64, C++)

Answer (score 0):

We had some experience in modifying several CNN platforms. For orientation-independent pattern recognition tasks, one optimized computation approach is to use symmetrical kernels for all convolution layers and to replace the 1st flattened layer with a merged convolution layer (see "Transformationally Identical and Invariant Convolutional Neural Networks [TI-CNN] through Symmetric Element Operators" https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03636). We successfully implemented fast algorithms on Caffe, PyTorch, and Darknet (GPU & CPU) platforms by changing im2col+gemm (2-6 times faster) and FFT (~1.5 faster) codes and using a fraction of memory buffer with dih4 symmetrical kernels. For a 3x3 kernel, naive convolution for using a dih4 kernel only takes 3 multiplications for each matric multiplication so Winograd does not have an advantage and is not needed in the symmetrical kernel mode. Tensorflow GPU convolution process uses cuDNN library for im2col+gemm, we could not change its im2col. But we can force all its kernels to be symmetric (either in C++ or python level) but computation and memory cannot be saved besides reducing 0-360 degrees to 0-45 degrees (the other 7 wedges of angle sections are identical to 0-45 degrees when dih4 symmetrical kernels are employed) if rotation data augmentation is used.